# Peer container consuming too much memory even when no memory-intensive operation is happening

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have a single peer v1.4 Fabric setup. I'm doing 5 parallel transactions on my chaincode with a simple for loop. My input data size is around 1 MB for every transation. Only one of the transactions is getting succeeded, all others are failing with the error `MVCC_READ_CONFLICT` which is an expected error.

The issue however is, the peer container memory usage goes extremely high ~3 GB during these transactions, and even when all of them return the response, the memory usage of the peer container remains the same. When I restart the peer, only then does the memory usage resets to its normal value i.e. ~200 MB.

Could anyone please help me with this issue? I ran the peer container in debug mode but couldn't find anything concrete. I don't even know where to start from.

Let me know if you want to check the logs or any configuration.

Comment: How are you measuring the memory utilisation, i've seen this behaviour before if you don't take the memory cache value into account, ie used_memory = memory_stats.usage - memory_stats.stats.cache
see https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerStats

Comment: I'm monitoring the memory usage using docker stats.

Comment: Go runtimes can have different memory profiles, so try using the latest 1.4 if you aren't already, but 1.4 is out of LTS now so won't be updated I would suggest trying the latest 2.2 release to see if that makes a difference. Finally have a look at portainer which can graph the memory usage of a container so you can get a history of the memory usage